# error on import preprocessing python library

Tags: python, typeerror, preprocessor

The actual code is just importing preprocessing, what am i doing wrong here?
How can i fix this? I am using code from github repo: [sbrt2017](https://github.com/igormq/sbrt2017)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/home/glauber/unifesp/forgers/sbrt2017/extras/make_dataset.py", line 8, in <module>
import preprocessing
File "preprocessing.py", line 14, in <module>
import librosa
File "/home/glauber/unifesp/forgers/sbrt2017/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/librosa/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
from . import core
File "/home/glauber/unifesp/forgers/sbrt2017/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/librosa/core/__init__.py", line 104, in <module>
from .time_frequency import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
File "/home/glauber/unifesp/forgers/sbrt2017/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/librosa/core/time_frequency.py", line 10, in <module>
from ..util.exceptions import ParameterError
File "/home/glauber/unifesp/forgers/sbrt2017/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/librosa/util/__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
from .utils import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
File "/home/glauber/unifesp/forgers/sbrt2017/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/librosa/util/utils.py", line 111, in <module>
def valid_audio(y, mono=True):
File "/home/glauber/unifesp/forgers/sbrt2017/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/librosa/cache.py", line 49, in wrapper
if self.cachedir is not None and self.level >= level:
File "/home/glauber/unifesp/forgers/sbrt2017/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/joblib/memory.py", line 847, in cachedir
DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: Looked like so many errors. It is nearly impossible to help you if you donot share the code.

Comment: the code is in the github repo, i shared it kkkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on line 847 of memory.py on the joblib package i had a warning.warn that was expecting a string but got a DeprecationWarning instead and it blowed up